# Wrong amplitude of convolution using numpy fft

Tags: python, numpy, fftw

I try to convolve a rectangle function in [-1/2, 1/2] with itself using fft. The convolution should be a tent shaped function, see figure below.

[image: rect wave and its convolution]

The code is below. In the 3rd to last line I add /50 so it appears correct - I have no idea what the normalization factor should be. And my question is how to normalize the power of a fft result, so the subsequent application of ifft gives the correct result?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft, fftshift, ifftshift
N = 1000
t=np.linspace(-10, 10, N)
dt = t[1]-t[0]

data = 1.0*(np.abs(t)<0.5)
data_fft = np.fft.fft(data)

plt.hold(1)
plt.plot(t, (ifft(data_fft**1)), 'r')
plt.plot(t, ifftshift(ifft(data_fft**2)) / 50.0, 'g')
plt.xlim(-4,4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The `np.fft` computations are correct; what is incorrect is that you expect these computations to give different results. It appears that you trying to verify Fourier transform properties of continuous-time signals by discretizing the latter and applying discrete Fourier transform (FFT). I would not recommend this approach due to subtle but critical differences between the continuous and discrete time domains.

Comment: @Stelios You are exact right, I am trying to verify the convolution property of the continuous Fourier transform. Could you please elaborate on the "subtle but critical differences"? I was expecting a straightforward relation between the two, no more than some normalization.

Comment: This is a rather deep topic. Just to give you an idea, consider for example the rectangular pulse signal. Whereas the continuous-time version has a well defined notion of "area", which is obtained by integration of the singal and is equal to `1`, no such notion exists for the discrete-time version. The only "similar" quantity in the discrete-time version is the sum of the sample values, which is equal to `50`. However this value will be different if you choose a different sampling period (`dt`).

Comment: @Stelios Thank you for your reply. But how about the sampling "interval" of the rectangle function. If you discretize it into 50 points, then the gap between the samples is 1/50. With numerical integration like the rectangle rule, you still have area 1 -- and this is independent of how many sample you use if you consider it from a numerical integration perspective.

Comment: Sure, however, this observation is relevant in the case where you want to compute the Fourier integrals numerically. In that case you should do the integration manually (or using a numerical integration function) and not use (I)FFT. The (I)FFT algorithm does not incorporate any sampling period information, i.e., it always implicitly assumes a normalized sampling period of `1`.

Comment: @Stelios I read numpy's fft documentation here (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html) and found what you said: the sampling period is 1. This appears strange to me but for now I will just do the Fourier integration without fft until I got time to dive deeper into the fft method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You actually do recover the convolution, but as it is discussed in the comments, there is a normalization issue due to discretization.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#module-numpy.fft), `fft` is implemented like this:

$$ A_k = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} a_m \exp \{ - 2\pi i \frac{mk}{n} \} $$

with $A_k$ being the Fourier-coefficients, $a_m$ the $m$-th element of your signal vector and $n$ the length of the signal.

Squaring this gives you

$$ A_k^2 = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \sum_{m'=0}^{n-1} a_m a_{m'} \exp\{ - 2\pi i \frac{(m+m')k}{n} \} \} $$

Now, applying `ifft` to the squared Fourier-transform gives you, using the `ifft`-definition from the documentation:

$$ \text{ifft}(A_k^2)_{m''} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \sum_{m'=0}^{n-1}a_m \exp\{ - 2\pi i \frac{(m+m'-m'')k}{n} \} \}$$

With the observation, that

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \exp\{ - 2\pi i \frac{(m+m'-m'')k}{n} \} = \delta_{m+m', m''} $$

you end up with

$$ \text{ifft}(A_k^2)_{m''} = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \sum_{m'=0}^{n-1} a_m a_{m'} \delta_{m+m', m''} = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} a_m a_{m'' - m}
$$

This is actually how `np.convolve` is [defined](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) (except for some padding). If you use `np.convolve` on your `data`, you end up with the same result (except for some padding), so within the `numpy`-world, you did exactly what you set out to do, i.e. verify, the convolution property of the Fourier transform. As noted in the comments however, neither `fft` nor `convolve` "know" anything about your descretization, so you have to take care of that manually by multiplying the results with `dt`.